# A 4-dimensional Markov chain

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, transition-matrix

Consider a 4-dimensional Markov chain with states $(a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{N}^4$.

The transition rule is the following:
\begin{align}(a,b,c,d) \rightarrow \begin{cases}
(a+1,b,c,d) \;\;\;\; \text{ with probability }p_x &\text{ if }ad>bc\\
(a,b,c+1,d) \;\;\;\; \text{ with probability }1-p_x &\text{ if }ad>bc\\
(a,b+1,c,d) \;\;\;\; \text{ with probability }p_y &\text{ if }ad\leq bc\\
(a,b,c,d+1) \;\;\;\; \text{ with probability }1-p_y &\text{ if }ad\leq bc\\
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Denote $P_t$ the probability distribution at time $t$, and assume $P_0(a,b,c,d) = \delta(1,1,1,1)$, i.e. the initial state is $(1,1,1,1)$ with probability 1.

**I'm trying to describe $P_t$ but am having some trouble.**

**What i've done:** I was thinking to define a recursive relation (denoting $(a-1)$ instead of $(a-1,b,c,d)$ for simplicity):

$$P_t(a,b,c,d) = P_{t-1}(ad>bc)\big[p_x P_{t-1}(a-1) + (1-p_x)P_{t-1}(c-1)\big] + P_{t-1}(ad\leq bc) \big[p_y P_{t-1}(b-1) + (1-p_y)P_{t-1}(d-1)\big]$$
but am not sure how to compute $P_t(ad>bc)$.

$f(a,b,c,d) = ad-bc$ seems to me like a Lyapunov function, and I know vaguely that Lyapunov functions are used to determine whether states are transient/recurrent. Is this useful here?

**Ultimately,** my goal is to describe the usual quantities of interest (stationary states, distribution of hitting times, etc.) for this process. So if $P_t$ isn't the way to go, I'm happy to use other methods.

Comment: Where did this Markov chain arise?

Comment: @AlexR. Good question, it's related to a reinforcement learning problem where we have two potential sources of reward (call them coins), $x$ and $y$, with probabilities of reward $p_x, p_y $ respectively. $(a,b,c,d)$ are the counts of successes and failures of both coins, and we flip coin $x$ if $ad>bc$ and $y$ if $ad\leq bc$.

Comment: Heuristically this is a pair of 2-D walks, and the $ad-bc>0$ condition asserts whether the volume of the parallepipid generated by $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ is positive or negative signed, which is equivalent to $(a,b)$ "crossing over" $(c,d)$.

Comment: @AlexR. Oh I see, so the parallelopiped would be formed with three of the vertices being $(a,b), (c,d)$, and $(0,0)$. They "cross over" when $(a,b) = \alpha(c,d)$ and so the volume is zero. $ad>bc$ corresponds to $(a,b)$ being "above" the line through $(0,0),(c,d)$ since this is when the slopes $a/b > c/d$

Comment: And then we have two 2d random walks $(a,c),(b,d)$ where the first walker moves if $ad>bc$ and the second moves if $ad\leq bc$... does this seem right? I don't know how one would analyze this from here (looking for hitting time distributions and stationary states and such)

Comment: Could you try to simulate this distribution numerically and report back with the distributions of $a,b,c,d$? While there's no stationary distribution (your walk never comes back to any point), a proper renormalization say by $1/n$ where $n$ is the number of steps may yield an asymptotic distribution for each coordinate$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by no means a complete answer.  If anything, it may be empirical evidence that this is a hard problem.

I've been trying to get some computational results for the problem of determining the probability that some state $(a,b,c,d)$ is ever reached.  If this step is reached, the first coordinate was increased $a-1$ times, the second $b-1$ times, and so on, so each path to the state has the same probability, and the problem is reduced to the problem of counting the paths.

Now to get to $(a,b,c,d)$ the last step may have increased the first coordinated, and we came from state $(a-1,b,c,d)$.  Since we increased the first coordinate, it must be the case that
$$(a-1)d-bc>0\iff ad-bc>d$$  The last step may have increased the second coordinate, so we came from $(a,b-1,c,d)$ and $$ad-(b-1)c\leq0\iff ad-bc<-c$$
If the last step increased the third coordinate, we came from $(a,b,c-1,d)$ and
$$ad-b(c-1)>0\iff ab-cd>-b$$
If the last step increased the fourth coordinate, we came from $(a,b,c,d-1)$ and
$$a(d-1)-bc>0\iff ab-cd\leq a$$

I wrote a little python script to do compute the number of paths:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache 
def paths(a,b,c,d):
    if min(a,b,c,d)==0:
        return 0
    if (a,b,c,d) == (1,1,1,1):
        return 1
    answer = 0
    D = a*d-b*c
    if D > d:
        answer += paths(a-1,b,c,d)
    if D <= -c:
        answer += paths(a,b-1,c,d)
    if  D > -b:
        answer += paths(a,b,c-1,d)
    if D <= a:
        answer += paths(a,b,c,d-1)
    return answer
 
for a in range(1,5):
    for b in range(1,5):
        for c in range(1,5):
            for d in range(1,5):
                p = paths(a,b,c,d)
                if p > 0:
                    print(f'({a},{b},{c},{d}): {p} path{"s" if p>1 else ""}')
```

The output is listed at the end of this answer.  There seems to be a complete lack of symmetry.  For example, there are $10$ paths to $(4,3,4,4)$, but only
$4$ paths to $(3,4,4,4)$ and no paths at all to either $(4,4,3,4)$ or $(4,4,4,3)$.  At time $t$ there are $2^t$ paths that can have been followed, and since the sum of the coordinates is $t+4$, there are only $\binom{t+3}3$ states that the chain can be in.  We might expect that for large $t$ a substantial fraction for such states have a positive probability of being visited, but I have no idea how to attack even this question.

```
(1,1,1,1): 1 path
(1,1,1,2): 1 path
(1,1,2,2): 1 path
(1,1,2,3): 1 path
(1,1,3,3): 1 path
(1,1,3,4): 1 path
(1,1,4,4): 1 path
(1,2,1,1): 1 path
(1,2,1,2): 1 path
(1,2,1,3): 1 path
(1,2,2,2): 1 path
(1,2,2,3): 2 paths
(1,2,2,4): 2 paths
(1,2,3,3): 1 path
(1,2,3,4): 1 path
(1,2,4,4): 1 path
(1,3,1,1): 1 path
(1,3,1,2): 2 paths
(1,3,1,3): 2 paths
(1,3,1,4): 2 paths
(1,3,2,2): 1 path
(1,3,2,3): 3 paths
(1,3,2,4): 7 paths
(1,3,3,3): 1 path
(1,3,3,4): 2 paths
(1,3,4,4): 1 path
(1,4,1,1): 1 path
(1,4,1,2): 3 paths
(1,4,1,3): 5 paths
(1,4,1,4): 5 paths
(1,4,2,2): 1 path
(1,4,2,3): 4 paths
(1,4,2,4): 11 paths
(1,4,3,3): 1 path
(1,4,3,4): 3 paths
(1,4,4,4): 1 path
(2,1,1,2): 1 path
(2,1,2,2): 1 path
(2,1,2,3): 1 path
(2,1,3,2): 1 path
(2,1,3,3): 1 path
(2,1,3,4): 1 path
(2,1,4,2): 1 path
(2,1,4,3): 2 paths
(2,1,4,4): 1 path
(2,2,1,3): 1 path
(2,2,2,3): 1 path
(2,2,3,3): 1 path
(2,2,3,4): 1 path
(2,2,4,2): 1 path
(2,2,4,3): 1 path
(2,2,4,4): 2 paths
(2,3,1,4): 2 paths
(2,3,2,4): 2 paths
(2,3,3,3): 1 path
(2,3,3,4): 3 paths
(2,3,4,2): 1 path
(2,3,4,3): 2 paths
(2,3,4,4): 4 paths
(2,4,3,3): 1 path
(2,4,3,4): 4 paths
(2,4,4,2): 1 path
(2,4,4,3): 3 paths
(2,4,4,4): 7 paths
(3,1,1,2): 1 path
(3,1,2,2): 2 paths
(3,1,2,3): 1 path
(3,1,3,2): 3 paths
(3,1,3,3): 2 paths
(3,1,3,4): 1 path
(3,1,4,2): 3 paths
(3,1,4,3): 4 paths
(3,1,4,4): 2 paths
(3,2,1,3): 1 path
(3,2,2,3): 2 paths
(3,2,3,3): 2 paths
(3,2,3,4): 1 path
(3,2,4,3): 2 paths
(3,2,4,4): 1 path
(3,3,1,4): 2 paths
(3,3,2,4): 4 paths
(3,3,3,4): 4 paths
(3,3,4,4): 4 paths
(3,4,4,4): 4 paths
(4,1,1,2): 1 path
(4,1,2,2): 3 paths
(4,1,2,3): 1 path
(4,1,3,2): 6 paths
(4,1,3,3): 3 paths
(4,1,3,4): 1 path
(4,1,4,2): 9 paths
(4,1,4,3): 7 paths
(4,1,4,4): 3 paths
(4,2,1,3): 1 path
(4,2,2,3): 3 paths
(4,2,3,3): 5 paths
(4,2,3,4): 1 path
(4,2,4,3): 7 paths
(4,2,4,4): 2 paths
(4,3,1,4): 2 paths
(4,3,2,4): 6 paths
(4,3,3,4): 10 paths
(4,3,4,4): 10 paths
```

Answer (score 1):

**Q)** What are the recurrent states?

Once you leave a state, you can't get back to it. Therefore the states don't communicate. Therefore no state is recurrent, ie all states are transient.

**Q)** What are the stationary states?

The states are all transient implying no stationary states.

**Q)** What is the hitting time of a state given by $\{a,b,c,d\}$?

Starting at $\{0,0,0,0\}$, we can move only right or up. Therefore the process only hits parts of the $\mathbb N^4$ grid. Most states are not hit. Therefore can we describe a finite hitting time?

Comment: Right, so I guess these are trivial for the process $(a,b,c,d)$. More of interest would be for $f=ad-bc$, which I know is a sub or supermargingale depending on sgn$p_x-p_y$. Can you shed any light on the stationary states, hitting times etc for $f_t$?

Comment: I phrased the question poorly, but do you see the richer thing i'm trying to get at?

Comment: Actually I didn't get your question. Do you mean you'll have a different transition matrix?

Comment: Which transition matrices are you referring to? I mean that the subtle behavior of $(a,b,c,d)$ is linked to the process $f=ad-bc$ (perhaps this could be viewed as a 5th variable) since the dynamics are different depending on sgn$(f)$. Some interesting questions, e.g., are whether sgn$(f)$ converges (I think it should, if $p_x,p_y$ are both greater than 1/2) or what is the expected hitting time to go from $f_t=0$ back to $0$.

Comment: What i meant by transitions is this function that is part of your question. $\begin{align}(a,b,c,d) \rightarrow \begin{cases}
(a+1,b,c,d) \;\;\;\; \text{ with probability }p_x &\text{ if }ad>bc\\
(a,b,c+1,d) \;\;\;\; \text{ with probability }1-p_x &\text{ if }ad>bc\\
(a,b+1,c,d) \;\;\;\; \text{ with probability }p_y &\text{ if }ad\leq bc\\
(a,b,c,d+1) \;\;\;\; \text{ with probability }1-p_y &\text{ if }ad\leq bc\\
\end{cases}
\end{align}$. Does it change?

Comment: No, this is the definition. What are you suggesting would cause a change? I'm confused

Comment: If instead you had just in the transition function $a+d \geq b+c$ it would just be a martingale instead of a super or submartingale (do you see why?). Currently, if $f(t) = ad-bc$ and you ask the question when is $f(t)$ hit for a given t, that is still a hard question as it does not hit every t. If the question were instead. "If i define hitting time for x to be the first t $t$ such that $f(t)>x$ if x>0 and $f(t)<x$ if x<0", then it would be an interesting question. (which i don't have an immediate answer to).

Comment: Do you think you can ask that as a follow up question? It may be more useful to other users also that way rather than the discussion here in comments https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129616/is-it-ok-to-ask-a-new-related-question-in-the-comments

Comment: Well as nice as $a+d=b+c$ would be, it isn't the process I've defined, lol. And I'm not necessarily looking for hitting times for every $x$, but rather return times to $0$. And I still think this is the same original question, but rather realizing that $f$ may be a useful quantity to explore the question.

Comment: I would still like to describe $P_t$ (but realized, as you kindly pointed out, that the recurrence/transience/etc of $(a,b,c,d)$ are trivial!)

Comment: Right, that's why the initial condition is at $(1,1,1,1)$

Comment: Infinite Markov chains can have stationary distributions.  This one does not, because as you noted, once you leave a state, you never get back to it.  The number of steps to hit $(a,b,c,d)$ is $a+b+c+d-4$ if it is hit at all.  It seems more interesting to ask for the probability that the state is ever hit.  Because no state recurs, the whole machinery of Markov chains seems irrelevant to this problem.  It seems to be a question of counting paths on a graph.

Comment: @saulspatz right, it does have a combinatorial flavor to it -- I'm wondering how to write a formula for $P_t(a,b,c,d)$ which I would guess is Gaussian-like as time goes on.